# MVC3 entity update issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, edit

We have two models Person and Address. We have created one combined model of these two models as shown below.

```
public class Trust_Person_Master
{
    public Person_Master PersonMaster { get; set; }

    public Address_Master AddressMaster { get; set; }

    public Trust_Person_Master()
    {

    }

    public Trust_Person_Master(Person_Master personMaster, Address_Master addressMaster)
    {
        PersonMaster = personMaster;
        AddressMaster = addressMaster;
    }   

}
```

Now, we use this `Trust_Person_Master` model, to save person and address.

So following is the method to save and edit.

```
[HttpPost, Ajax(true)]
public JsonResult SaveTrust(Trust_Person_Master entity)
{
    int nCurrPersonId = entity.PersonMaster.Person_ID; 
    if (entity.PersonMaster.Person_ID > 0)
    {
        var update = db.Person.Find(entity.PersonMaster.Person_ID);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            TryUpdateModel(update);            
        }     
    }
    else
    {
        db.Person.Add(entity.PersonMaster);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    HttpContext.Application["TrustPersonSearch"] = null;    
    return Json(new { person_id = entity.PersonMaster.Person_ID, location_id = entity.PersonMaster.Location_ID });
}
```

But my problem is that when I edit person, i.e. just field of person master say first name, then that it executes the code as required without giving any error. But does not reflect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the `TryUpdateModel()` method. How are you updating the model ?

By looking at the code you have posted everything seems ok and should not give any problems, however I would like to see the way you are updating your entity, the problem seems to lie there.

Debug as much as possible and come back here with your findings.

Comment: Shouldn't this have been a comment? By reading it, I don't understand how this is answering the question. I agree that the question is very unclear but that's what the comments section is meant for - ask for additional details when a question is not clear enough.

Comment: solved the issue... actually I figured out that I don't need to use combined model of person and address... so sorry to bother you all